# how does activerecord know to perform an insert or update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Maybe some Ruby experts out there can shed some light on how `activerecord` know to do an `insert` or `update` when calling `save()`. What is the logic behind it? Does it check to see if the primary key is blank or something and if so does an `insert`, if not an `update`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Whilst it's fine for some people to say "RTFM" I rather the more walk-through-but-still-entirely-useless-when-Rails-3-comes-out-and-changes-everything response:

**How it works in Rails 2.3 (aka "today")**

[`save`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2537-2539) calls [`create_or_update`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2871-2876) which looks like this:

```
def create_or_update
  raise ReadOnlyRecord if readonly?
  result = new_record? ? create : update
  result != false
end
```

You can ignore the first line of this method as it only raises an error if the record is readonly (it isn't usually, but in the case of joins it may be). What we are interested in here is the second and third lines inside the method.

The second line calls [`new_record?`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2516-2518) which is defined as this:

```
  # Returns true if this object hasn't been saved yet -- that is, a record for the object doesn't exist yet; otherwise, returns false.
  def new_record?
    @new_record || false
  end
```

And the variable `@new_record` is set when the [`initialize`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2433-2443) (`new` calls `initialize`, and gives us a new object, some background Ruby-fu here) method is called.

So if this `@new_record` is `true` it'll call [`create`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2893-2906) and if it's false it'll call [`update`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2880-2889) which brings us to what you're after, I think.

Furthermore, when you find a record it does not call `initialize` and therefore does not set `@new_record`. If you noticed, the code behind `new_record?` was `@new_record || false`, meaning it will return false if `@new_record` was not set.

Let's say for example you want to find the last `Forum` record, so you would do `Forum.last`.

1. This calls the [`last`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L628-630) method on the `Forum` class, which inherits from ActiveRecord::Base
2. `last` [calls](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L614) the [`find`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L607-618) class method.
3. `find` [calls](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L614) [`find_last`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L1508-1528)
4. `find_last` [calls](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L1524) [`find_initial`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L1503-1506)
5. `find_initial` [calls](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L1505) [`find_every`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L1542-1557)
6. `find_every` [calls](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L1548) [`find_by_sql`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L660-662)
7. and [`find_by_sql`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L660-662) calls [`instantiate`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L1620-1661)

You'll see here that nowhere along this change is `@new_record` set and thus any record obtained by `find` will not be a new record.

Hope this helps you understand.

Comment: very nice answer and i think you for the time to took for you to write it. i'm also interested in knowing what would set @nw_record to false? would performing a find do that if it pulls a record from the database?

Comment: Is there anyway to modify the "new_record" attribute yourself

Comment: @HenleyChiu, no, not that I know of. You can override `new_record?` / `persisted?` on your model and run some custom code in that if you want different behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

It principaly relies on the [new_record?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002328) method.
This method returns true if it's a new record and false if it's not.

In fact it's not really hard.

- When you get an existing record, it's not new. So `new_record?` can direcly return false.
- When you create a new record (`Model.new`), `new_record?` will return true. It's a new record.
- When you save that new record, it's not new anymore. The internal variable `@new_record` gets updated. `new_record?` won't return true anymore.

To see when it happens, go to [ActiveRecord::Base](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb), line 2911

```
    self.id ||= new_id

    @new_record = false
    id
  end
```

Comment: You're linking to master when he's probably using 2.3.

Comment: That doesn't change my argument. But I have updated the link anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Check out activerecord's doc [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002329) and the source code [there](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L2823).

Comment: i have been reading through the docs and code and can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: You too are linking to master. He's probably using 2.3.